# how to set display 0 if database store as Null

Tags: sql, if-statement, stored-procedures

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_pbos001_list AS

SELECT t1.id
    , t1.customer_code AS cus_code
    , (
        SELECT SUM(transaction_amt - cleared_amt)
        FROM pbosdeposit
        WHERE customer_code = t1.customer_code
        ) AS total_deposit
    , (
        SELECT SUM(inv_amt)
        FROM pbosinvoice
        WHERE customer_code = t1.customer_code
        ) - (
        SELECT SUM(cleared_amt)
        FROM pbosdeposit
        WHERE customer_code = t1.customer_code
        ) AS total_outstanding
FROM customer t1
```

For the total deposit and total outstanding i want it to show '0' on display if in the database is NULL.
I try using if else but not working.

```
if(total_deposit = 'NULL')
set 0;
```

Comment: Do `total_deposit IS NULL` to test for NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using coalesce :

```
            CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_pbos001_list AS

            SELECT t1.id
                , t1.customer_code AS cus_code
                , coalesce((
                    SELECT SUM(transaction_amt - cleared_amt)
                    FROM pbosdeposit
                    WHERE customer_code = t1.customer_code
                    ),0) AS total_deposit
                , coalesce(((
                    SELECT SUM(inv_amt)
                    FROM pbosinvoice
                    WHERE customer_code = t1.customer_code
                    ) - (
                    SELECT SUM(cleared_amt)
                    FROM pbosdeposit
                    WHERE customer_code = t1.customer_code
                    )),0), AS total_outstanding
            FROM customer t1
```

Comment: Why is zero a string? That's a sum column .

Comment: Code Edited. You can remove quotes for numeric.

Comment: instead of 0 can i put 0.00?

Comment: @David  yes. IF your  result Sum is Decimal then you can put 0.0 or 0.00 also.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `COALESCE` to replace NULL values:

```
SELECT t1.id
    , t1.customer_code AS cus_code
    ,COALESCE((
        SELECT SUM(transaction_amt - cleared_amt)
        FROM pbosdeposit
        WHERE customer_code = t1.customer_code
        ),0) AS total_deposit
    , COALESCE((
        SELECT SUM(inv_amt)
        FROM pbosinvoice
        WHERE customer_code = t1.customer_code
        ) - (
        SELECT SUM(cleared_amt)
        FROM pbosdeposit
        WHERE customer_code = t1.customer_code
        ),0) AS total_outstanding
FROM customer t1
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server:

```
ISNULL(total_deposit, 0)
```

MySql:

```
IFNULL(total_deposit, 0)
```